# forfiles to delete files which its file size is lower than x

Tags: cmd

```
forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c del if @fsize LEQ 148576 echo @path"
```

I tried this to delete files which its file size is lower than `148576`, but It deleted all of files regardless of the size. Which point should I change to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is as follows.

```
if something matches/don't match/larger/smaller/like something_else do something.
```

Therefore it should be:

```
forfiles /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @fsize LEQ 148576 echo @path"
```

Replace `echo` with `del` once you are happy with the printed results.

We match the size with a value, if that matches the operator, we perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do this with PowerShell, the `-WhatIf` switch can be invaluable for experimenting without doing damage. When you are confident that the correct files will be deleted, remove the `-WhatIf` switch.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path '.' |
  ForEach-Object {if ($_.Length -le 148576) {Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf}}
```